# What are the requirements to breed a fireworks dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

So I came across this (and a forge) dragon today in the shop after a friend pointed it out to me. It suggests in the description that this is a limited time only dragon so that hints that there are restrictions to it. When trying to breed other limited time dragons I am wondering what other requirements may be on this dragon to evaluate its worth in breeding. I can see that it is a Fire and an Air combination so I am looking at what the Other requirements are to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Dragonvale Wikia](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Firework_Dragon):

> The Firework Dragon can be bred by selecting a fire dragon to mate with an air dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.
>   Breeding a fire dragon with an air dragon may also result in a Blazing Dragon.

It has a **Breeding time** of 6 hours (4 hours and 48 minutes on an upgraded island), and an **Incubation time** of 6 hours.

Note that you **must be level 14 or higher** in order to breed a Firework Dragon.

According to the in-game tool tip, the Firework Dragon will be available until **July 20th**. Apparently it can still be bred, though it doesn't appear in the shop anymore.

Having just managed to breed two of them in a row, I wouldn't worry *too* much about the limited availability.

Comment: More of what I am seeking is what makes the dragon a 'Limited' dragon. There are no time restrictions sited for it as of yet :/

Comment: I'd say it's a pretty safe bet that it's similar to the Solstice dragon. Available for a week past the actual holiday, with an improved chance *on* the holiday. Since no time restriction has been cited as of yet, other than it falling in the Limited category on the Wikia, I fear the question isn't able to be answered fully. I expect that to change soon, though.

Comment: @James As expected, the tool tip updated finally.

Comment: Seems the tips do not like me as I still have not seen any of them about this or that [other new dragon](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75083/how-do-i-breed-an-evergreen-dragon)

Comment: @James They both come in the same message. Evergreen is permanent! =D