# How do I breed an Evergreen Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

I see a new dragon, the Evergreen dragon has been created. How do I breed this dragon? How do I know when I'm going to get one? Are there any special requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Evergreen Dragon](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Evergreen_Dragon) can be bred by breeding a **Plant Dragon and a Cold Dragon**. If you get a breeding time of 10 hours, that means you'll get an Evergreen dragon. If you get a time of 6 hours, you got a Lichen dragon instead as this is the other possible result.

You'll need to be Level 9 to get this dragon, since that's the earliest you can get a Cold Dragon of any kind.

Can't find an Egg picture yet, but the Evergreen dragon looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I get it with lichen and plant both level 16 in EBI

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please avoid posting one line answer. Your answer lack any reference to back it up.